# git - renaming folder and new files

Tags: git

I have a git repo, containing the folder `A`.  Locally, I clone this repo, but then decide to rename that folder:

```
git mv A newfolder
git add -u newfolder
git commit -m "Folder rename"
```

Now, if I modify `A/stable` in my repo, then do a `git pull` locally, sure enough, I get:

```
newfolder/stable
```

**However**, if I create a *new* file in my repo, `A/fresh`, and do a `git pull` locally, I end up with
    `A/fresh`
instead of `newfolder/fresh` (that is, git creates a new folder named `A`, and puts the `fresh` file there).  Why is this rename not working with new files?

Answer (score 1):

Git will have no clue that `A` was replaced by `newfolder`.  If you created `A/fresh` file in a remote repo and then fetch/merge that into your local repo, it'll have no choice but to mimic the remote structure and create the folder `A`.

The solution here would be to push your changes (`A` becomes `newfolder`) to the remote repo before you create the `fresh` file.  Therefore, you'd be creating `newfolder/fresh` instead of `A/fresh`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely true: as I mentioned in the question, it works perfectly for modified files that already existing at the time of renaming.  Note that it is the local git that takes care of handling renames (so it does in fact know about the change).

Comment: Also, pushing the changes is not an option: this is a local-only change, and the repo is used by other people.

Comment: @SteveD Right, at the time of the renaming. Why do you expect that behavior after-the-fact? Unless I'm completely misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, I'd like that every file that gets pulled as `A/foo` is renamed to `newfolder/foo`.

Comment: @SteveD So on the remote, `A` will never be renamed to `newfolder`?

Comment: Correct - no changes to the remote, only locally. Basically, the local branch **only** pulls, never pushes.

Comment: @SteveD Yeah, that's not how that works.  I think your best bet here is to create a `post-merge` hook to do the filesystem leg work of moving the files to `newfolder` and deleting the empty `A` folder.

Comment: OK, the post-merge hook sounds promising.  My only concern is that this will delete the local copy of `A/`, and thus the local git will think I've made changes (saying I deleted a bunch of files).  How will that affect me?

Comment: @SteveD Yes, I agree, that's kind of rough.  I guess what you could do in your hook is just make a commit on those changes the hook does to prevent you from having to deal with them?  Not a real great answer, but I can't think of anything else.